# gitweb.cgi: "Premature end of script headers: gitweb.cgi"

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd, git

I'm running LAMP on Arch and now want the gitweb going on apache. Followed the instructions as in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitweb but on the gitweb directory (here `localhost/~myuser/gitweb`) I get:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
Premature end of script headers: gitweb.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Fri Jun 8 15:14:11 2012
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c DAV/2 PHP/5.4.3
```

Comment: Without additional information from e.g. the apache error log we won't be able to help. What happens if you execute the script yourself?

Comment: Ending up in `suexec.log` I see this: `[2012-06-08 13:29:51]: uid: (1000/myuser) gid: (1000/myuser) cmd: gitweb.cgi
[2012-06-08 13:29:51]: command not in docroot (/usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi)`

Comment: This is a security feature by suexec you are only allowed to execute a command within your document root, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html#model point 13

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading the page. But is there some major probability you have a solution for so I could test NOW?

Comment: Move gitweb into your docroot, e.g. your `public_html` folder. You could either try to setup a symlink or hard link if you don't want to copy the file into your folder but i'd assume only a hardlink would work.

Comment: Its a softlink now, but I think the methodical answer ought to be the suEXEC thing. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and resolved it by installing the `perl-cgi` package

```
$ sudo pacman -S perl-cgi
```

N.b, I debugged this by running the failing script directly, i.e,

```
$ cd /usr/share/gitweb/ 
$ ./gitweb.cgi
Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI module)(@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at ./gitweb.cgi line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./gitweb.cgi line 13.
```